# How to declare an attribute to hold functions that can return any type?

Tags: c#, function

I have a class to represent variables:

```
public class Variable {
    public string name;
    public TYPE type;
    public object value;
    public Action valueFunction = null;

    public Variable(string name, TYPE type, object value, Action valueFunction = null) {
        this.name = name; this.type = type; this.value = value; this.valueFunction = valueFunction;
    }
    //method I want to create
    public object GetValue(){
        if(valueFunction != null) return (object) valueFunction();
        return value;
    }
}
```

It's simple: I want someone to give a function to a `Variable`'s instance, so that if it has a function, it should return the value of the function (e.g.: `int intFunc(){return 4;}` or `string strFunc(){return "hello";}`), otherwise return `value`.

How can I have a `valueFunction` variable that holds a function that can return any type?

---

I'm thinking about `Func<object>` but I'm not sure if it's right or how to use it.

Comment: Have you considered using generics? Declaring a `Variable<T>` that holds a `Func<T>`

Comment: If you know in advance the return type, then declare var as {object} and then cast to required object

Comment: You are thinking in the correct direction, but `Action` returns no value you need to use `delegate` instead.

Comment: @muaz `Func<T>` would be better